# Solaris - Syncing via ftp with links

Tags: ftp, solaris

I am on Solaris and I need to sync a directory path with a ftp server.
Unfortunately a large part is made up with links which do not work with the ftpsync.pl script which uses a rsync-like mechanism.
Does anyone know an alternative with rsync style synchronisation via ftp which works with links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use mirror ( http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/utils/archivers/mirror/ ) to mirror a number of ftp sites around the world.  This copes with symbolic links.  I am unsure if this meets your 'rsync style synchronisation' requirement.

-- Ref